# Trying IRC example in python, client not visible in chat

Tags: python, irc

I am trying this example as a starting place to make an IRC client:

```
import sys
import socket
import string

HOST="irc.debian.org"
PORT=6667
NICK="_MauBot"
IDENT="_maubot"
REALNAME="_MauritsBot"
readbuffer=""

s=socket.socket( )
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
s.send("NICK %s\r\n" % NICK)
s.send("USER %s %s bla :%s\r\n" % (IDENT, HOST, REALNAME))

while 1:
    readbuffer=readbuffer+s.recv(1024)
    temp=string.split(readbuffer, "\n")
    readbuffer=temp.pop( )

    for line in temp:
        line=string.rstrip(line)
        line=string.split(line)

        if(line[0]=="PING"):
            s.send("PONG %s\r\n" % line[1])
```

I also connect to the `irc.debian.org` using `Xchat` program. The thing is that I can't see the `_maubot` as a user in the chat, neither I see someone with the name connecting or disconnecting. For creating such an application I need some way to test it, but there has to be something am doing wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "see .. as a user in the chat"? You didn't join a channel (try sending `JOIN #channel\r\n`), so there's nowhere to be seen..

Comment: I thought that there is some default channel for irc.debian.org it should be #debian. But even if I join using s.send("JOIN #acal\r\n") I dont see myself in Xchat if I join the same channel.

Comment: No, there are no default channels on that server. If `JOIN` did not work, you're doing something else wrong. Try to print the server's response. It's readable plaintext and should contain an error message. I suspect that your nick/user combination is invalid.

Comment: I'd recommend [simple_irc](https://github.com/whereswalden90/simple_irc) as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Try another server:
CHOOPA.NJ.US.DAL.NET

Your irc.debian.org doesn't like underline withn nick.

Just remove underline and see what happen.

Comment: this is just another irc-net. There are no problems having underlines in OFTC i am aware of.